# Expanding Notification Bar Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I am trying to **expand the notification bar** programmatically in the android studio.
I have tried using the following code:-

```
private void ExpandNotificationBar(){
    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.EXPAND_STATUS_BAR) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        return;

    try{
        Object service = getSystemService("statusbar");
        Class<?> statusbarManager = Class.forName("android.app.StatusBarManager");
        Method expand = statusbarManager.getMethod("expand");
        expand.invoke(service);
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        Log.e("StatusBar", e.toString());
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Expansion Not Working", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

This however returns

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: expand []
```

I am unable to find any solution for this as the method is not even in official APIs.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

**EDIT**:
I've only tried the method in the emulator as of now. I will post here again if I find anything new when trying on an actual smartphone.

**EDIT_v2**:
Tried on an actual device. Yet no success. One thing I noticed was, that the permission is not being asked to the user. Even though I am checking for it.

**Android manifest file**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.EXPAND_STATUS_BAR"/>
```

**Asking Permission**

```
private void GetPermissions(){
    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.EXPAND_STATUS_BAR) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.EXPAND_STATUS_BAR}, 1);
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

    switch (requestCode){
        case 1: {
            if(grantResults.length == 0 || grantResults[0] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Permission Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

The **GetPermission()** method is being called in OnCreate function only.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: expand []
```

This error say `android.app.StatusBarManager` class does not have a method with name expand.you can check method of this class [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/56a2301/core/java/android/app/StatusBarManager.java).

`android.app.StatusBarManager` have `expandNotificationsPanel` to

> Expand the notifications panel.

then in code we should find `expandNotificationsPanel` method with reflection

```
private void ExpandNotificationBar(){
    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.EXPAND_STATUS_BAR) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        return;

    try{
        Object service = getSystemService("statusbar");
        Class<?> statusbarManager = Class.forName("android.app.StatusBarManager");
        Method expand = statusbarManager.getMethod("expandNotificationsPanel"); //<-
        expand.invoke(service);
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        Log.e("StatusBar", e.toString());
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Expansion Not Working", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanx a lot man. Works like a charm. Apart from the question if you don't mind, can you explain to me how do we manage to do this even though it is not given in the official documentation.

Comment: You're welcome, that's all about dependency injection in java. –

Answer (score 0):

Need to add a required permission, that is: "android.permission.EXPAND_STATUS_BAR"

Comment: I've already added that in my manifest and I am also asking for permission.  Please check the **EDIT_v2** in question. Thank you